# Creating a Diagonal Line in Python/only using Nested Loops

Tags: python, nested-loops

Alright, so I've been staring at my screen for the past few hours trying to solve this problem. I have to create a diagonal line that which could have any character.

Needs to look like something like this:

```
*
  *
    *
```

---

This is my code that I have right now.

```
# Draw a Diagonal
row = 1
while row <= size:
# Output a single row
col = 1
while col <= row:
    # Output the drawing character
    print()

    # The next column number
    col = col + 1

# Output a newline to end the row
print(end=drawingChar)

# The next row number
row = row + 1
print()
```

---

and it doesn't come out close to anything like a diagonal line! Could use some insight, thank you for the help. I have to use nested loops. I saw a couple other questions like this on the search, but they don't work for my assignment.

---

Comment: Hmm, I'm confused; where are the nested loops to begin with?

Comment: Sorry I'm new to the community, my teacher mentioned we needed to use nested loops for the assignment. so for example the triangle pattern went like this:

Comment: row = 1
while row <= size:
    # Output a single row
    col = 1
    while col <= row:
        # Output the drawing character
        print(drawingChar, end=' ')

        # The next column number
        col = col + 1

    # Output a newline to end the row
    print()

    # The next row number
    row = row + 1
print()

Comment: Is it a random character each time, or an already designated character? And are all the characters the same in the diagonal pattern?

Comment: I have a variable called drawingChar which allows the user to input whatever char they want, and it's the same character throughout the whole pattern.

Comment: also a variable called size which allows the user to choose the size of the shape

Comment: How does the size change? Does it increase horizontally, vertically, or both?

Comment: # Get the size and drawing character from the user
size = input('Please enter the size: ')

# Validate the input, exit if bad
if size.isdigit():
    size = float(size)
else:
    print('You didn\'t enter a number:', size)
    sys.exit(1)

# Input the drawing character
drawingChar = input('Please enter the drawing character: ')

# Output an empty line
print()

Comment: The size is static so if you had a square and wanted it size 4. It would be 4  by 4

Comment: Would you be able to take and/or submit a picture of the prompt for the assignment?

Comment: You can't just say "it doesn't come out close to anything like a diagonal line". What is it doing wrong? We can't guess.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with a simple for loop:

```
>>> for i in range(5):
    print(' '*i, end = '*\n')


*
 *
  *
   *
    *
```